Matplotlib plotting plt.plot(t,y) VS df.plot(y)
what's the problem, why the these two versions of code do not produce the same graphs ? they are just reversed in order.
My df.index is a date_time object and Y_FIT['BFGS'] is an array.
CODE 1 :
plt.plot(df.index, Y_FIT['BFGS'])
df.Column1.plot()


CODE 2:
df.Column1.plot()
plt.plot(df.index, Y_FIT['BFGS']);



Are you using jupyter? If no, do you see 2 matplotlib windows?

Can't reproduce anything like that. Please provide a [mre]

create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

as I know df.plot(y) is some kind of wrapper on plt.plot(t,y) - but it doesn't means that it doesn't have some other code which make something else. You would have to check source code for df.plot(y)
